# NodeJS V8: Get List of Unoptimized Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, v8

Is there a quick way to get the list of unoptimzied functions for a Nodejs application? Google Chrome offers that for browser via the profiler: http://puu.sh/i5zPd.png.

I know you can use `node --trace_opt --trace_deopt app.js` to have the list in real time but it's not the most friendly to use.

Comment: What is an "unoptimized function"?  Are you really just asking about a profiler for node.js?

Comment: A function such as `%GetOptimizationStatus(myFunction) !== 1`.

Comment: http://bahmutov.calepin.co/detecting-function-optimizations-in-v8.html

Answer (score 0):

[node-tick](https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick) can output a similar list of optimised and unoptimised functions as Chrome does in web developer tools.

Run your script with `node --prof app.js`. After it has finished, there should be a log file in the working directory containing tick information. `node-tick-processor` outputs the list of functions in few different orders. Functions marked with * are optimised and non-optimised are marked with ~. Unfortunately this does not tell why optimisations are not applied.